# Extract numbers from string and add them with php

Tags: php

I have a long string like below:

`$string = "age1:32,age2:25,age3:52,..."`

Now I want to extract the age numbers in this string and then add the numbers together and determine the average age.
I was able to extract the numbers with the help of the following code

`$numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $string );`

but the output I get is like this and I cannot add the numbers together.

output:
`322552`

Answer (score 1):

Using `preg_match_all` to find all age values followed by `array_sum` to find the total/average we can try:

```php
$string = "age1:32,age2:25,age3:52,...";
preg_match_all("/age\d+:(\d+)/", $string, $matches);
print_r(array_sum($matches[1]) / count($matches[1]));  // 36.333333333333
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to write the preg function if my string is like this `available12available15available22available11`

Comment: You are asking a new question in a comment.  Don't do that; open a new question.

Comment: my new question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72944697/extract-numbers-from-a-long-string-and-add-them-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart the fullstring match after each colon, then match one or more digits.
2. `preg_match_all()` returns the number of matches (`$count`).
3. Divide the sum of the matches by the number of matches.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cbAsl))

```
$string = "age1:32,age2:25,age3:52,...";
$count = preg_match_all('/:\K\d+/', $string, $m);
echo array_sum($m[0] ?? []) / $count;
// 36.333333333333
```

If you wanted to grab all numbers, just use `\d+`. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GWSaD))

```
$string = "available12available15available22available11...";
$count = preg_match_all('/\d+/', $string, $m);
echo array_sum($m[0] ?? []) / $count;
```